# Is middleware called when redirect to url is used in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have route which uses `url` , `middleware` and `calls` controller method.

If I redirect to same url used by route then is middleware called/used?

Or should I redirect to route instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route middleware is called on every request which matches the route it is defined on, regardless of how the request is initiated. App middleware is called on every single request.

Comment: That's true only for GLOBAL middlewares $middleware.What if it is for specific ROUTE in $routeMiddleware ?

Comment: @umeshkadam as stated in my answer, if the request matches a route, the route middleware will be called.